# jquery photo gallery with fading effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, image-gallery

I found great tool for Image slide show as in the link below

http://thiagosf.net/projects/jquery/skitter/

One can set up Image Slide with multiple effects quickly, unfortunately i am not able to make it work for me i simply want and Image Effect with image fade In/Out and with no Navigation as it is shown in the Skitter.
I am not sure if i can use skitter to replicate the effect as show in the example 2.

I am using the following code for skitter but it is not giving me the desired effect. When i set "dots: false"

- It hide the dots but automatically show the number navigation which i don't want.
- I want Image to Fade In/Out but i cant find that option with the script.

Am i doing something wrong or effects which i am looking for are not possible with the skitter Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".box_skitter_large").skitter({
            numbers_align: "center", 
            dots: true, 
            preview: false, 
            focus: true, 
            focus_position: "leftTop", 
            controls: false, 
            controls_position: "leftTop", 
            progressbar: true, 
            progressbar_css: { 
                top:'0px', 
                left:'0px', 
                height:0, 
                borderRadius:'0px', 
                width:0, 
                backgroundColor:'#000', 
                opacity:.7 
            }, 
            animateNumberOver: { 'backgroundColor':'#555' }, 
            enable_navigation_keys: true
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out this Jquery Plugin

http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/simplest-jquery-slideshow

it matches very close to what you require..

A proper documentation for the same is also available..